# Implement IDataErrorInfo on a class that already has a property indexer with a matching signature

Tags: c#, properties, idataerrorinfo, indexer

I want a class that has an indexer string this[string propertyName]. This will access a dictionary that is serializable with the class to allow for dynamic properties. In addition, I want to implement IDataErrorInfo to allow for validation against those properties.

The problem is that they have matching signatures. Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of implicitly implementing the interface you can also implement it explicitly this way:

```
string IDataErrorInfo.this[string key]{get { return [..]; }}
```

Comment: How do I reference the explicit implementation from my binding if it is private? Are explicit interface implementations are treated as public? If so, won't two indexers with the same signature cause a problem in the binding?

Comment: Hmm.. good question. You could add a pure (WPF?) binding helper property `public IDataErrorInfo DEI {get {return this;} }` -- maybe others have a smarter solution for this.

Comment: What about [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IndexerName("Property")]? Can I use an explicit indexer name in the binding path to decide between the two indexers?

Comment: I think this is for named indexers, but C# does not support named indexers.